# conditional compilation statement in limits.h

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, conditional-compilation

I am not able to understand the following statement from the file limits.h. What is the use of this statement and what does it accomplishes?

```
/* If we are not using GNU CC we have to define all the symbols ourself.
   Otherwise use gcc's definitions (see below).  */
#if !defined __GNUC__ || __GNUC__ < 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It checks if your program is compiled by some other compiler than GCC, or some very old GCC version.

Comment: @kotlinski: I guess, the "2" in last of the if statement is the gcc version.

Answer (score 2):

It checks whether you are not using a Gcc compiler Version 2  or Gcc some other versions.
using this pre-processor macro we can some portable codes.